# Is it possible to store and analyze multiple values in single column row in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with quite large data sets, but for context of my question consider the following example: I begin with 2 data frames. `DF1` contains informations about farms (location, number of workers, etc) and `DF2` contains information about which crops are harvested by each farm.

```
DF1                               
#  Farm    Num_Workers  State
#1 Tom's   20           FL
#2 Joe's   5            TX
#3 Sam's   9            CA


DF2
#  Farm    Crop
#1 Tom's   Corn           
#2 Tom's   Wheat            
#3 Sam's   Corn   
#4 Sam's   Green Beans 
#5 Sam's   Apples
#5 Sam's   Melon 
#6 Joe's   Wheat   

#Without aggregating creates duplicates
left_join(df1, df2, by = "Farm)
#  Farm    Num_Workers    State     Crop
#1 Tom's   20             FL        Corn           
#2 Tom's   20             FL        Wheat            
#3 Sam's   9              CA        Corn   
#4 Sam's   9              CA        Green Beans 
#5 Sam's   9              CA        Apples
#5 Sam's   9              CA        Melon 
#6 Joe's   5              TX        Wheat
```

As you can see, there are multiple entries for each farm in `DF2`, which introduces duplicate rows in `DF1` when performing a `left_join` with the data frames (and incorrectly inflates the total sum number of workers, `num_workers`). To prevent duplicates, I aggregate `DF2` by farm to produce `DF3`. I then `left_join` this new data frame with `DF1` to create the `FINAL` data frame.

```
DF3 <- aggregate(Farm ~ Crop, data = DF2, paste, collapse = ",")
FINAL <- left_join(DF1, DF3, by = "Farm")

FINAL                               
#  Farm    Num_Workers  State  Crop
#1 Tom's   20           FL     Corn, Wheat
#2 Joe's   5            TX     Wheat
#3 Sam's   9            CA     Corn, Green Beans, Apples, Melon
```

I am still a bit green in R and I am hoping to see is if there if a way I could still perform analysis on the individual values of the `Crop` column, i.e. find the frequency of each crop, frequency of each crop by state, etc. Or would I have been better off perhaps keeping the two data frames distinct?
Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Instead of `paste`, you could convert it to a `list` column i.e. `aggregate(Farm ~ Crop, data = DF2, FUN = c)` and then you can go over the `list` with `lapply/sapply` etc

Comment: You should directly left join. There will be no duplicate rows. Also note that two rows with similar firms but different crops are not duplicated.  In no way will this inflate the number of workers

Comment: @akrun and Onyambu: What do you think about my solution?

Comment: @Onyambu I updated the question to demonstrate how duplicates are created with left join.

Comment: @akrun I will be looking into this approach, thank you!

Comment: @Nicole there are no duplicates in your data. Your data is correct. You  can group_by(Farm) and you will see that there are only 3 groups ie three farms etc

Comment: @akrun can you elaborate on how I can see the totals/frequency of each crop with your list approach?

Comment: @Nicole If the object creatd is `DF3`, then the `DF3$Farm` is a `list`  So we use `lapply(DF3$Farm, function(x) proportions(table(x)))` perhaps

Answer (score 1):

First group by `Farm`.
then `summarise` and use `paste` with `collapse`
then `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
DF2 <- DF2 %>% 
  group_by(Farm) %>% 
  summarise(Crop = paste(Crop, collapse = " "))

DF1 <- DF1 %>% 
  left_join(DF2, by ="Farm")

DF1
```

Output:

```
  Farm  Num_Workers State Crop                         
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr> <chr>                        
1 Tom's          20 FL    Corn Wheat                   
2 Joe's           5 TX    Wheat                        
3 Sam's           9 CA    Corn Green Beans Apples Melon
```

Comment: If you are using tidyverse, can also use `str_c(Crop, collapse = ' ')`

Comment: How would I go about actually quantifying the number of crops with this approach? This seems to produce close to same result I had already.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go about this is through the dplyr package.  First create a count column and then do the Join.

```
###Create a count column

DF2$count = 1
#### Join tables first ###
DF3<- left_join(DF1, DF2, by = "Farm")
#### Then sum count and combine 
DF3<-DF3 %>%
group_by(Farm, Crop, Num_Workers) %>%
summarize(number_of_crops = sum(count))

Final<-DF3 %>%
group_by(Farm, Num_Workers) %>%
summarize(Crop_Num = paste(number_of_crops, collapse =","),
         Crop =  paste(Crop, collapse =","))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
df3 <- left_join(df1, df2) 


df3 %>% count(Crop) # Frequency of crop


df3 %>% count(State, Crop) # Frequency of crop by state
```

Comment: Ok, I see how this works now. Initially I was nervous about this approach since I'm actually working with a list of multiple dfs with matching dfs, but I'm just now coming to fully appreciate piping. Thank you so much for your patience and taking the time to demonstrate this to me!

Comment: @Nicole You should not collapse them into a string. Note that you do not have duplicates.

Comment: I may be using the wrong term, but what I am referring to by "duplicates" is that if I'm working with this new data frame and go to total the number of workers `sum(DF3$Num_Workers)` now returns the incorrect value `[1] 81` instead of the desired output `[1] 34`. I see now that I can probably produce the correct output with some combination of grouping and piping, but everything I've tried so far on this mock dataset has thrown an error or returned a tibble.

Comment: @Nicole That is not how to find the number of workers. That will only work if each worker had one crop. But in the dataset above, a worker can have multiple crops. What errors re you getting?

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in totaling the number of workers (so, sum of the `Num_Workers` for each `Farm`) independent of the Crop variable, as I was able to in the original data frame DF1. Even after making sure the column was numeric `df3$Num_Workers <- as.numeric(df3$Num_Workers)`, `df3 %>% group_by("Farm") %>% sum("Num_Workers")` prints the message `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables`.  No luck with `sum(count())` either. Previously the error was something to the effect of "Object not found".

Comment: @Nicole. I see what you mean. You need to either stick on using tidyverse or just use base R.  if you want to know the number of  Farms just do `df3 %>%distinct(Farm) %>%count()`